# Add remove with numbering indicated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So currently I can easily add and remove multiple `textarea`

But what I'm trying to  do is to put numbering per specific `textarea`

Here's my textarea

as you notice my default text area is `Step 1`

But I wanted to do is when I clicked add it will show another textarea that says

`Step 2`

```
  <div class="optionBox">
                <div class="block">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Step 1</label>
                      <textarea class="form-control rounded-0" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="10"></textarea>
                    </div>

                     <span class="remove">Remove</span>

                </div>
                <div class="block"> <span class="add">Add Option</span>

                </div>
            </div>
```

My Javascript

```
 $('.add').click(function () {
$('.block:last').before(' <div class="block"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Step</label><textarea class="form-control rounded-0" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="10"></textarea></div><span class="remove">Remove</span></div>');
});
```

Here's the current output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To make this work you can add a `span` element with no content to the `label` within each `.block`. Then you can create a function which updates the number within that `span` based on the index of the element every time you add or remove a `.block`.

I would also strongly suggest that you clone elements instead of adding lots of HTML in to your JS logic, as this violates the Separation of Concerns principle due to tying the JS too closely with the HTML. In your case this can be done by simply adding one extra class on to the `.block` which holds the `textarea` elements. Try this:

```js
$('.add').click(function() {
  let $lastBlock = $('.block.step:last');
  let $clone = $lastBlock.clone().insertAfter($lastBlock);
  $clone.find('textarea').val('');
  updateStepCounts();
});

$('.optionBox').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  if ($('.block.step').length > 1) {
    $(this).closest('.block').remove();
    updateStepCounts();
  }
});

let updateStepCounts = () => $('.block label span').text(i => i + 1);
updateStepCounts();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="optionBox">
  <div class="block step">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Step <span></span></label>
      <textarea class="form-control rounded-0" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <span class="remove">Remove</span>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <span class="add">Add Option</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi I appreciate your effort to explain it very well to me, it works but the remove isn't working.

Comment: I've added the remove logic for you. Remember that you need to use a delegated event handler in the dynamically added fields

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `div.block` surrounding the "add option" `span` and used `.append` on the newly added `div.block-container` element instead of `.before` to add the next `textarea` to the bottom of the options container. i think this reads a little better symantically.

Also using string interpolation i am able to insert the total number of `div.block` + 1 to track the number of textareas visible on the page.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.add').click(function () {
  const numberOfBlocks = $(".block").length;
  
  $(".block-container")
    .append(`
      <div class="block">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Step ${numberOfBlocks + 1}</label>
          <textarea class="form-control rounded-0" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="10"></textarea>      
        </div>
        <span class="remove">Remove</span>
      </div>`
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="optionBox">
    <div class="block-container">
        
    </div>
    <span class="add">Add Option</span>
</div>
```